# A4988 and battery power

Tags: stepper-motor

I have battery power (9v) for stepper motor (auto-tracker for telescope mount). I need micro stepping and high torque (0.1 N*m). I decided to use bipolar stepper and A4988 because there are cheap modules from eBay.

But: I need to rotate stepper very slowly (about 1 step per second), so most of time the motor stay without rotation and A4988 produce a holding current, but I need no holding torque (there are no external torque that can rotate my motor).

How to maximize battery life in my case. Maybe just set "enable" pin of A4988 to 1 between rotations? But I have another questions in this case:

1) Can I lost steps if I will set enable pin to 1 between every steps? In data sheet there is note that if I will use sleep pin, then after wake up A4988 go to HOME state, so I will lost steps. But there are no notes about behavior of enable pin.

2) How microcontroller can know when step have executed (before set enable pin to 1)?

Maybe there are another solutions. I need at least 5 hours of 9v alkaline battery, 0.1 N*m, single step each second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A4988 data sheet here

(1) The data sheet says that the /ENABLE input does not destroy "state"information. 
However, as Anindo notes, while there is no external torque, the motor will apply "pull in torque" when depowered. It MAY be possible to use the current limiting setting to reduce holding current to a minimum and to increase it when actually stepping, but this is not a certain solution, and it  adds complexity which may make the overall solution unattractive.

On page 10 it says:

**Enable Input  /ENABLE**

This    input   turns   on  or  off all of  the  FET    outputs.
When    set to  a   logic   high,   the outputs are disabled.
When    set to  a   logic   low,    the internal    control enables the outputs 
as  required.
**The   translator  inputs  STEP,   DIR,    and MSx,    as  well    as  the internal    sequencing  logic,  all remain  active, independent of  the /enable INPUT STATE.**

---

(2) You may also be able to dynamically alter the effective sense resistors that control maximum current. These MAY latch, on a step by step basis, which would make this method impractical.

Data sheet says:

- At   each    step,   the current for each    full-bridge is  set by  the value   of  its external    current-sense   resistor    (RS1 and    RS2),   a   reference   voltage (VREF), and the output voltage  of  its DAC (which  in  turn    is  controlled  by  the output  of  the translator).

Comment: I know about current limiting, but changing logical level on a chip's pin is more simple solution :) What negatives follows from switching "enable" pin? If no, I have only one problem: I need a way to know a time when step done.

Comment: "The translator... remain active": so, when I enable chip again, I get currents through coils exactly the same as before disabling chip? And I can continue steps/microsteps as if I didn't disable the chip for a time?

Comment: Russell, for microstepping, there would be holding current on the coils. If one were to stop this current (by using ENABLE or any other way), the stepper would snap to the closest detent point, would it not? If yes, that isn't suitable for the stated purpose, of telescope control.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I believe you are correct. The motor will snap to the closest full step position when you remove holding current. It might be better to use a gear reduction drive instead of microstepping. That would allow driving the motor with full steps so it wouldn't move when you remove holding current. It also multiplies the motor torque, potentially allowing the motor to be driven at lower current, and thus extending battery life.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh - I took the statement "but I need no holding torque" at face value but, as you note,, the motor will apply "pull in torque". It MAY be possible to use the current limiting setting to reduce holding current to a minimum and to increase it when actually stepping, but this is not a certain solution, and it  adds complexity which may make the overall solution unattractive.

Comment: I need no holding torque because the motor work only against friction of an axis of telescope mount, i. e. the axis holds its position itself because of friction. The motor used only for rotation. I want to minimize time when there are currents through coils.

Comment: Corvus - Anindo's argument - which is correct for some types of motors and probably for your one, is that when you remove power from the motor then THE MOTOR itself will provide powered off torque that pulls it towards the closest stepping position. This WILL be true for a brushless DC motor which has permanent magnets (usually in the rotor) and iron stator laminations, BUT will not not true for a BLDCM with an ironless stator and generally not true for a motor which has no permanent magnets but only wound magnets. | IF your motor "cogs" when you turn it when it is powered off then it is ...

Comment: ... providing powered off torque. | If your motor turns freely by hand when powered off with no cogging / saliency / grittiness then it has no powered off torque when off position. | What is your motor brand and model? | Does it "cog" when turned with power off.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh - See above comments. If the motor is not salient (which is possible) it may work OK with depowering. Either could apply. An "ironless" stator BLDCM could be used.

Comment: A powered brake could be used. This could be magnetic. The brake control signal would need to be synchronised with the stepping signal. Gets messy. Sounds like fun.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Am in agreement with your comments. Key question: Does the chosen stepper motor cog when unpowered?